# How Can I delete auto created SuperUser of Ignite

Tags: ignite, sqlline

I have an Azure Kubernetes Service. I deployed the Apache Ignite image on it.
It works well and I'm using ThinClient to connect to the Ignite. Also, authentication has been enabled.

In the first deployment, Ignite creates a superuser that name and password are "ignite".
I created my own user and tested to connection. It succeeded.

I would like to delete the user created by Apache Ignite, but I couldn't do it.
How can I delete the user?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default superuser can't be removed, but you should be able to change the default password `ALTER USER "ignite" WITH PASSWORD 'newPassword';`

Comment: Thanks, Alexandr. It worked. But my new user couldn't change the superuser password. I need to change with the superuser itself.

Comment: Also, If the question is useful please vote for it.