# How to change default ignite superuser password

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I tried to enable ignite authentication on the server.
When I did that by changing the XML configuration, I tried to create new user and remove the default one, but I'm getting errors that I can not remove default superuser. I tried do it from the level of ignite user and also from the new created one. Is there any way to define the password in the XML for the default ignite user? Because I'd like to have it automated.

I tried to:

- Modify the XML configuration
- Prepare `sqlline.sh` with a `-e` argument

**Solution:**

1. Update ignite do version 2.15 (the problem was since 2.10 version)
2. Use `sqlline.sh -u jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost -e "[SQL]"`
   //Sth. there is a need to change "" to '' or /"/". Be aware of that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648401/how-can-i-delete-auto-created-superuser-of-ignite) question.

You need to log in using the default `ignite` user and change its password.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there is any other solution. I need to automate that. Since I put on stackoverflow that question I found that from 2.10 version there is a problem with -e parameter, so if I would update ignite to version 2.15 then I could use sqlline.sh -e approach.